# How to separate different text files based on the file number

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have 20 text files in a folder. file name is represented as

```
a 1.txt,a 2.txt,a 3.txt...
```

some files have different operation and some other is different

I have passed file numbers in to a `list lst_num=[1,6,15,16]` like this all need to write in one file and files not in list should do write into another file

```
for file in fnames:
    nume=os.path.splitext(file)[0].split()[1]
    lst_num=[1,6,15,16]
    fp = open(file, 'r').read()
    for i in lst_num:
        if file=="a "+str(i)+".html":
            print(file)
        else: 
            print('--'+file)
```

all the files in list pass to one text file 
not in list to another file

Comment: Do you want to separate the files, or to concatenate them?

Comment: Is the file name `1.txt` or `a 1.txt` ?

Comment: just  i need seperation of  files here

Comment: It is "a 1.txt"

Comment: Why are you comparing `file== "a 1.html"` when it is `*.txt`?

Comment: You don't need to do double for loops, plain old set difference would do @SS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is comparing to an `html` file, but your file extension is actually `txt`
Also your double for loop will end up printing the same file name multiple times

You actually don't need to iterate over the files and `lst_num`.
Just create the file names using `lst_num` to write to one file, then get the file names to write to another file by taking the difference between all files and `lst_num` files

```
fnames = ['a 1.txt', 'a 2.txt'....]
lst_num=[1,6,15,16]

#All files in lst_num
in_list_files = ['a {}.txt'.format(item) for item in lst_num]

#All files outside lst_num
not_in_list_files = list(set(fnames) - set(in_list_files))

print(in_list_files)
print(not_in_list_files)
```

The output will be

```
['a 1.txt', 'a 6.txt', 'a 15.txt', 'a 16.txt']
['a 2.txt', 'a 3.txt', 'a 4.txt', ....]
```